# PHP using preg_replace : "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" error

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to take a string of text like so:

```
$string = "This (1) is (2) my (3) example (4) text";
```

In every instance where there is a positive integer inside of parentheses, I'd like to replace  that with simply the integer itself.

The code I'm using now is:

```
$result = preg_replace("\((\d+)\)", "$0", $string);
```

But I keep getting a

> Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash.

Warning

Any thoughts?  I know there are other questions on here that sort of answer the question, but my knowledge of regex is not enough to switch it over to this example.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering why all the answers say to add backslashes when they're already there, it's because they weren't showing originally.  @Christopher, you should always format code samples (especially regexes!) by either indenting it four spaces or enclosing it in backticks.

Comment: Since you are new to stackoverflow, I would like to tell you that you can **accept** an answer that you found most helpful by clicking the check mark next to that answer.

Comment: In general: Do set the leading slash `/` after the first quotes: `preg_replace("/\...)`

Answer (score 49):

You are almost there. You are using:

```
$result = preg_replace("((\d+))", "$0", $string);
```

- The regex you specify as the 1st
  argument to `preg_*` family of function
  should be delimited  in pair of
  delimiters. Since you are not using
  any delimiters you get that error.
- `(` and `)` are meta char in a regex,
  meaning they have special meaning.
  Since you want to match literal open
  parenthesis and close parenthesis,
  you need to escape them using a `\`.
  Anything following `\` is treated
  literally.
- You can capturing the integer
  correctly using `\d+`. But the captured
  integer will be in `$1` and not `$0`. `$0`
  will have the entire match, that is
  integer within parenthesis.

If you do all the above changes you'll get:

```
$result = preg_replace("#\((\d+)\)#", "$1", $string);
```

Comment: Gotcha.  So the delimiters can be just about anything? I have seen '#' and '/' both work.

Comment: Yes, you can also use ~~, @@, {}, ##, //, !! and many more :). But usually we use a delimiter which does not appear in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the tip for enclosing in #, that isn't mentioned on any of the php regex tester websites.

Answer (score 11):

1. You need to have a delimiter, the `/` works fine.
2. You have to escape the `(` and `)` characters so it doesn't think it's another grouping.
3. Also, the replace variables here start at 1, not 0 (0 contains the FULL text match, which would include the parentheses).

   $result = preg_replace("/((\d+))/", "\1", $string);

Something like this should work. Any further questions, go to [PHP's `preg_replace()` documentation](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) - it really is good.

Answer (score 4):

Check the docs - you need to use a delimiter before and after your pattern: `"/\((\d+)\)/"`

You'll also want to escape the outer parentheses above as they are literals, not a nested matching group.

See: [preg_replace manual page](http://us.php.net/preg_replace)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$string = "This (1) is (2) my (3) example (4) text";
$output = preg_replace('/\((\d)\)/i', '$1', $string);
echo $output;
?>
```

The parenthesis chars are special chars in a regular expression. You need to escape them to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash.,

try typing your parameters inside "/ .... /" as shown bellow. Else the code will output >>> Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash.

```
$yourString='hi there, good friend';
$dividorString='there';
$someSstring=preg_replace("/$dividorString/",'', $yourString);

echo($someSstring);

// hi, good friend
```

.
.
worked for me.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: @Toto ive edited the answer, this answers question: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash.,