# preg_replace with (.*) doesn't work

Tags: php, preg-replace

I would like to replace a string like

```
title="CONTSTANTWORD fnwif 740933840 j iowej902 ijofiowi CONTSTANTWORD"
```

with

```
id="detectLink"
```

The word CONTSTANTWORD is, surprisingly, constant. The rest,

```
fnwif 740933840 j iowej902 ijofiowi
```

is variable.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2192217/2776747), so I edited the code to this:

```
$html = preg_replace('title="CONTSTANTWORD (.*) CONTSTANTWORD"','id="detectLink"',$string);
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work. Does anyone know what my preg_replace code should look like?

Edit: this is the error I get:

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in ..... on line 8

Comment: try setting back references around the expression `/EXPRESSION_HERE/`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP using preg\_replace : "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" error.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527657/php-using-preg-replace-delimiter-must-not-be-alphanumeric-or-backslash-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$test = 'title="CONTSTANTWORD fnwif 740933840 j iowej902 ijofiowi CONTSTANTWORD"';
$html = preg_replace('#title="CONTSTANTWORD (.*) CONTSTANTWORD"#','id="detectLink"',$test);
var_dump($html);
```

Outputs

```
string(15) "id="detectLink""
```

You need to put a delimiter around your regex